# 'ui_mainwindow.h' file not found

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I just installed Qt on my Windows 10 PC. I create a new project, and write some lines in the mainwindow.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
  delete ui;
}
```

But the Qt environment gives me errors on some lines:

```
mainwindow.cpp: 2: 10: error: 'ui_mainwindow.h' file not found
mainwindow.cpp: 4:24: error: unknown type name 'QWidget'
mainwindow.cpp: 6: 12: error: allocation of incomplete type 'Ui :: MainWindow'
mainwindow.h: 7: 7: note: forward declaration of 'Ui :: MainWindow'
mainwindow.cpp: 8: 7: error: member access into incomplete type 'Ui :: MainWindow'
mainwindow.h: 7: 7: note: forward declaration of 'Ui :: MainWindow'
```

When compiling:

```
Cannot run complier 'clang ++'
```

How do I fix these problems? How and where to install clang++?

Comment: This probably means either `uic` was not run or its outputting in a folder that is not in the include search paths.

Comment: Make sure `ui_mainwindow.h` exists. Did you run `qmake`?

Comment: Are you using qt-creator? If not qmake or CMake?

Comment: I'm not sure about anything :-)
 I just installed Qt Creator, launched it.  Select "New Project", I chose Qt windgets app and created an application.  After that, these files were created with errors.
 My installation package weighs Qt> 70gb, that I did not install?

Comment: And yes, I installed the application at D: \ Qt.  But I save projects D: \ Qt projects

Comment: As far as we can see, you haven't created a `.ui` file. `ui_mainwindow.h` won't be generated without a corresponding ui file. (Normally, this is auto-generated by creating a set of new files; File → New File or Project [Ctrl+N] → Files and Classes → Qt → Qt Designer Form Class.) You might also need to configure your compilers and kits (Preferences → Kits) to fix the compiler issue.

Comment: I am not sure why an auto generated project would not build. Check your filesystem to see if the .ui file exists in the project folder.

Comment: did you choose qmake or cmake when creating the new project? If you chose qmake try right-clicking on the project name and select "run qmake" , then try building it again with ctrl-B.

Answer (score 4):

You should have QT += widgets on your .pro project file

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your build directory. `Settings -> under "Deskstop Qt...." build ->` then if you have wrong build directory (if it was wrong it would be red). You need to change it.

The new build directory must be the folder where you save your Qt project when you just created it.